# Java 8 - How to read file line by line in java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I saw this type of question asked already but they doesn't seems to answer mine problem. :(

I have a text file "file.txt" and its content something like this

> abcd
>   efgh
>   ijkl

now i want that , different type of lines stored by different String variable in my programme
for example

```
String firstLine , String secondLine , ThiredLine;
```

and when i print above Strings then output would be

```
firstLine :: abcd & secondLine :: efgh & thiredLine :: ijkl
```

is it possible to do it using **readLine()** method or any other?

**Thanks In Advance** :)

Comment: So the file has only three lines ?  i dont think having as many variables as lines is a good approach to solve any problem. What do you want to do with these variables?

Comment: This is the part of "Store Player Runs in cricket" 11 player ; 11 lines ; and and 11 variables ;)

Comment: *"Is it possible to do it using `readLine()` method?"* Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you're going about seems a bit crude. There are many other ways to go about doing this. Many others have submitted answers, but here's an alternative one.

Also please note that as of Java 7, there is now automatic resource management for classes that implements the AutoCloseable interface.

With that being said, here's a way of doing it.

```
    String[] lines = new String[11];  //11 players
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file path here"))) {
        String line = null;
        int index = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines[index++] = line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can reference the `java.nio.file.Path` and the `java.nio.file.Files` class in java api.
   you can get the answer about the question.
   First step you should get the Path object by the file path.
   Second step you can read line by line the content by the Files.readAllLines(Path path) method.
   the example in the below:

```
   Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(filePath);
   List<String> datas = Files.readAllLines(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it that way, you could write your code like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("file.txt");
String firstLine = sc.nextLine();
String secondLine = sc.nextLine();
String thirdLine = sc.nextLine();
```

However, it would be more convenient to use an array and a `for` loop:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("file.txt");
String[] lines = new String[3];
for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    lines[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an `ArrayList` and a `while` loop. The advantage to doing it this way is that this code will work regardless of the number of lines in the file:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("file.txt");
ArrayList<Sting> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(sc.nextLine());
}
```